# Slow connection to Google Cloud Sql from external server

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have successfully deployed `Google Cloud SQL` with phpmyadmin running on App Engine.  When connecting the database directly using App Engine the performance is fine but while connecting it via sql client or external server it takes too long to load.

Can anyone tell me what might be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Can you better define "too long to load"? You mean start up time? Inserts? Selects? Does performance change if you change to asynchronous writes?

Comment: @cflewis I am connecting to the Cloud SQL via the server located in Asia. Example Site running local Mysql [link](http://hotel.frontdesk.my) & Site Running Cloud SQL [link](http://cloud.frontdesk.my) . The site using Cloud SQL take longer time to load.

Comment: Without knowing more about your code, it's hard to tell. We don't have Cloud SQL instances in Asia right now, so the latency between where your instance is (either USA or Europe) could be part of it if there's a slow link. Try pinging your instance using `ping [ip address]`. If it's a lot higher than the local MySQL instance, that's probably the root cause.

You will reduce the latency between the web page and the database by hosting the page using AppEngine, and then the latency hit is decreased as you're only sending one data payload back (the built page, vs multiple DB connections).

Comment: @cflewis Ping test to the cloud SQL took average 1.60 ms. I guess at this moment the only solution is to host using AppEngine if we are going to use Cloud SQL.

Comment: The 1.6 ms number is a bit misleading. That's the latency from your client in Asia to the closest Google server. Since there is no Cloud SQL deployment in Asia at the moment, the actual latency is much higher than 1.6 ms. Other than AppEngine, running your application on Google Compute Engine should also offer low latency.